# Knockout.js mapping not displaying data bound on child observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a child observable array on an defined object. When the object from the server is returned and populated into the knockout observable the data fails to display. However the data is in the view model can can be verified with debugging. I have created jsFiddle that illustrates the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/Y2Fr6/

My view models are defined as such

```
function PropertyLease(propertyLeaseId, propertyCatalogId, confirmedBldgSF, leaseExpenseStructure, leaseTermRate, propertyType, yearBuilt)
{
    var self = this;
    self.PropertyLeaseId  = ko.observable(propertyLeaseId);
    self.PropertyCatalogId = ko.observable(propertyCatalogId);
    self.ConfirmedBldgSF = ko.observable(confirmedBldgSF);
    self.LeaseExpenseStructure = ko.observable(leaseExpenseStructure);
    self.LeaseTermRate = ko.mapping.fromJS(leaseTermRate);
    self.PropertyType = ko.observable(propertyType);
    self.YearBuilt = ko.observable(yearBuilt);
}

function PropertyLeaseTermRate(propertyLeaseTermId, propertyLeaseId, from, to, annualRatePSF)
{
    var self = this;
    self.PropertyLeaseTermId = ko.observable(propertyLeaseTermId);
    self.PropertyLeaseId = ko.observable(propertyLeaseId);
    self.From = ko.observable(from);
    self.To = ko.observable(to);
    self.AnnualRatePSF = ko.observable(annualRatePSF);
}
```

and I update them when the data is returned from the server like

```
viewModel.LeaseSearchResults.removeAll();
var vmLeaseSearchResults = viewModel.LeaseSearchResults();
for(var idx = 0; idx<result.LeaseSearchResults.length; idx++){
    var data = result.LeaseSearchResults[idx];
    vmLeaseSearchResults.push(
        new PropertyLease(
            data.PropertyLeaseId, 
            data.PropertyCatalogId, 
            data.ConfirmedBldgSF, 
            data.LeaseExpenseStructure, 
            data.LeaseTermRate, 
            data.PropertyType, 
            data.YearBuilt
            )
        )
}
viewModel.LeaseSearchResults.valueHasMutated();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Arg!

P.S. The second View Model `PropertyLeaseTermRate` isn't used until the user makes a choice from a data grid. ;-) Sorry for the confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

- If you are writing `var vmLeaseSearchResults = viewModel.LeaseSearchResults();` because of the `()` you are referencing the underaying array and not the observable array itself. So when you are calling `vmLeaseSearchResults.push` Knockout won't be notified so you need the call `valueHasMutated`.

  But the correct approach is to let Knockout do the change tracking so you should remove the `()`: so `var vmLeaseSearchResults = viewModel.LeaseSearchResults;` then you don't need the `valueHasMutated` call.
- You have the same problem with the `var vmLeaseTermRate = viewModel.SelectedLease().LeaseTermRate();`

  However here you have a second problem. When you call `viewModel.SelectedLease(value);` knockout will start to bind your details list in the `<div data-bind="with: SelectedLease">`. But your model (`value`) does not have the `LeaseTermRate` defined yet, so Knockout will silently fail on the `ko foreach: LeaseTermRate`.

  To fix it just move the `LeaseTermRate` declaration before the `SelectedLease` call:

  ```
  var value = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);
  value.LeaseTermRate = ko.observableArray();
  viewModel.SelectedLease(value);
  var vmLeaseTermRate = viewModel.SelectedLease().LeaseTermRate;
  ```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/t4xTN/)

Comment: I like your second answer. However your first answer poses a performance issue. The reason why I suspend the observable and access the raw underlying array is for data-sets larger than a few hundred items. So calling `valueHasMutated()` is just fine for me. I don't mind writing and extra line of code if it allows me to updated with a few thousand rows of data. 
What really got me was the declaration of the `value.LeaseTermRate = ko.observableArray();`. I guess I forgot that knockout has no room to re-bind properties once model is sent to it.